# Tensorflow: Placeholder Size Issue in Tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

I'm following [Tensorflow's Deep MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#deep-mnist-for-experts). When I ran the following line

```
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 748)'
```

It seem unhappy with how I'm feeding `x`. I set `x` to be the following placeholder:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 748])
```

I checked that `batch[0]` is a float32 numpy array of size 50x748. What's the proper way of feeding an array to `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a typo in your placeholder, notice

```
Cannot feed value of shape (50, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 748)'
```

It's shape 784 in the feed, while the placeholder is 748, so you just need to change the placeholder to

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
```

Also don't worry this happens to everyone :)